# Eigenvalues of A when AA'A=A

Tags: linear-algebra

In some presentation the speaker said that pushing AA'A-A  to 0 makes encourages singular values of A to be either 0 or 1, can anyone tell me where this follows from?

Comment: Please specify, what is $A$ exactly? (A linear transformation between inner product spaces?)  Perhaps it will help to note that $(A'A)^2 = A'A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your statement implies that $(AA')^2 = AA'$, so $AA'$ is a projection. Projections only have eigenvalues of 1 or 0. Since the singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $AA'$ the original statement follows.